# deleting selected range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that simply delete the range in excel.. but I don't know why that if you click the button to delete the selected range it happens the entire range are deleting and I don't know why. Can you help me thanks in advance

```
Private Sub cmdDel_Click()
    cmdEdit.Enabled = False: cmdAdd.Enabled = False
    cmdClose.Caption = "CANCEL"
    If MsgBox("Delete this record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Message") = vbYes Then
       Range("A" & r & ":" & "V" & r).Delete

       r = 0
       MsgBox "Record deleted!", vbExclamation, "Message"
    End If
    Call UserForm_Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Please confirm the value for r at the point that the `Range("A" & r & ":" & "V" & r).Delete` line is executed. I suspect that it is zero, which would lead to the answer given by Siddharth Rout below.

Comment: Where are you inputting r, and if you select a range what does r become? This will only delete a single row once r is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple because the value of `r` is 0 so your string actually becomes

```
Range("A:V").Delete
```

Set a value of `r` before deleting and the problem will go away

Also if you are manually selecting the range and deleting the range then use this

```
Selection.Delete
```